# Is there a JavaScript way to do file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, javascript

Here is the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Here is how I would use it in an Ajax call, if I don't find a pure client way to do this.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

Is there way to do this client side instead so I don't have to ajax the string over?

Comment: What's the content of that file you want to "include"?

Comment: Similar to the example above..it accepts a URL as a parameter..the URL is user defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do

JS code:

```
$.post('phppage.php', { url: url }, function(data) {
    document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = data;        
});
```

PHP code:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

That would get you the contents of the url.

Answer (score 10):

It's 2020 and some modern approach;

```
async function file_get_contents(uri, callback) {
    let res = await fetch(uri),
        ret = await res.text(); 
    return callback ? callback(ret) : ret; // a Promise() actually.
}

file_get_contents("https://httpbin.org/get", console.log);
// or
file_get_contents("https://httpbin.org/get").then(ret => console.log(ret));
```

Comment: This is spot on and works a treat, thanks for the es6 example.

Comment: how do you get the value into a variable to use?

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript cannot go out and scrape data off of pages. It can make a call to a local PHP script that then goes on its behalf and grabs the data, but JavaScript (in the browser) cannot do this.

```
$.post("/localScript.php", { srcToGet: 'http://example.com' }, function(data){
  /* From within here, data is whatever your local script sent back to us */
});
```

You have options like JSONP and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing at your disposal, but both of those require setting up the other end, so you cannot just choose a domain and start firing off requests for data.

Further Reading: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 7):

This function will return the file as a string just like the PHP `file_get_contents()`.

```
function file_get_contents(uri, callback) {
    fetch(uri).then(res => res.text()).then(text => callback(text));
}
```

However unlike PHP, JavaScript will go on to the next statement, not waiting for the data to return.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Not in a general sense. Cross-domain restrictions disallow Javascript code from doing this.

If the target site has [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (cross-origin resource sharing) set up, you can use XMLHttpRequest to load files. Most sites do not, as it's off by default for security reasons, and is rarely necessary.

If you just need to include an HTML page, you can stick it in an `<iframe>` element. This is subject to some layout gotchas, though (the page ends up in a fixed-size element).

Comment: ...can I do any analysis of the iframe...maybe grab the title some how?

Comment: @CS_2013 No, not if the `iframe` isn't a document from your domain.

Comment: Nope. The contents of the frame are pretty much completely off-limits.

Comment: No. Cross-domain resource sharing is set up the way it is for very good security reasons. Read Michal Zalewski's excellent book "The Tangled Web: A Guide to Securing Modern Web Applications" for details.

Comment: Well...it needs to be ammended...because I'm taking up more network resources now...adding another hop...yet still getting the data I intended to get....keep the security...kill the inefficiency.

Comment: Got to wonder how many billions of page requests this creates per day, month, etc. on the web.

Comment: @CS_2013: How would you "keep the security"? I think you are misunderstanding the problem at a very fundamental point.

Answer (score 2):

Or You can use php.js library. Which allow some php functions for javascript. file_get_contents() function one of them.

```
<script>
var data = file_get_contents('Your URL');
</script>
```

You can find more info about php.js : http://phpjs.org/

Comment: This will be subject to the same origin policy as well

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be useful for you:

An npm package with the "file-get-contents" method for node.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-get-contents

***It is asynchronous so if you are using express it should be used like this***

```
app.get('/',  async (req, res)=>{
    //paste here the code below
}
```

> Example
>
> ```
> const fileGetContents = require('file-get-contents');
>  
> // A File request
>  
> try {
>     let data = await fileGetContents('/tmp/foo/bar');
>  
>     console.log(data);
> } catch (err) {
>     console.log('Unable to load data from /tmp/foo/bar');
> }
>  
> // Or a HTTP(S) request
>  
> fileGetContents('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').then(json => {
>     const pokemon = JSON.parse(json);
>  
>     console.log(`Name of first pokemon is ${pokemon.name}`);
> }).catch(err => {
>     console.err(`Unable to get content from PokeAPI. Reason: ${err.message}`);
> });
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div id="svg">

  </div>
  <script>

    function file_get_contents(uri, callback) {
         fetch(uri).then(res => res.text()).then(text => 
        {

            var xmlSvg =text;
            console.log(xmlSvg );
            document.getElementById('svg').innerHTML = xmlSvg;
        })
    }

    
    var uri ='You-urlllllllll-svg';

    file_get_contents(uri);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you add clarification around this answer? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

```js
function file_get_contents(filename) {
    fetch(filename).then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
        document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data;
    });
}
file_get_contents("url");
```

```html
<span id="id"></span>
```

Comment: Please explain your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi, please explain your code to make it helpful for others.

Comment: This function only gets the URL and processes it as a PHP file_get_contents.Inside the js function fetch the URL and put the data using inner HTML method

Comment: Please edit the answer and put that in to make your answer helpful in search results.