# How to retrieve html elements returned by an external php site?

Tags: php, html

There's an external site http://example.com/phprender.php

Which returns the following html elements

```
<div id="phprender">
  <p id='101'>ABC</p>
  <p id='102'>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

How do I retrieve the data "ABC" so I can use that data to display in my own site?

Comment: Use `file_get_contents` to download the HTML, and `DOMDocument` to parse it.

Comment: if its legal to scrape contents from that particular site, then you should look into HTML Parsers in PHP, DOMDocument in particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DomDocument to parse HTML, and DOMXpath to retrieve:

```
    $url="http://example.com/phprender.php";
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $content=file_get_contents($url);
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $elements=$xpath->query("//p[@id='101']");
    if (!is_null($elements))
    foreach ($elements as $ele) {
         echo $ele->nodeValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/phprender.php');
echo $html;
?>
```

**For client way**
[Is there a JavaScript way to do file_get_contents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693518/is-there-a-javascript-way-to-do-file-get-contents)

Comment: the site where I want to get the data to display on the site does not support php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693518/is-there-a-javascript-way-to-do-file-get-contents

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use javascript approach, make sure the external site have cors disabled. You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Headers). Then use jquery to load it:

```
$("#content").load("services.html #IdOfelementToLoad");
```

you can use #101 in your case.

Comment: I don't have access to the external site.

Comment: then you may want to use php approach instead. Try http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download
then substr $returned_content to get only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Solution**

You can use file_get_contents and perform a regular expression match like this:

```
preg_match('/<p.*>(.*)<\/p>/i',file_get_contents('http://example.com/phprender.php'), $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**JQuery Solution**

With JQuery you can use get for retrieve remote html like this:

```
$.get( "http://example.com/phprender.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  var myMatch = data.match(/<p.*>(.*)<\/p>/i);
});
```

or using DOM instead match.