# Invoking a CORS enabled API from JQuery Ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get data from a URL like 
https://www.gov.uk/api/organisations/skills-funding-agency

It resolves in browser and returns Json response. But not returning anything when invoked from jquery Ajax.
I tried jsonp

This might be Offtopic/particular case but I will improve this question to a amore generic one, once I recieve an answer

Comment: Add some example code pls.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to run a simple ajax post to a php file that grabs the contents via file_get_contents() as recommended here: [Is there a JavaScript way to do file_get_contents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693518/is-there-a-javascript-way-to-do-file-get-contents)

Comment: DId you try this?, as this API is expecing some origin header and denying my Request.

Comment: Yep, tested and working via file_get_contents. [PHP Fiddle Here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2dhg-6yqu)