# How can I get a html source code of any website using jquery/javascript like php's file_get_content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Is is even possible? or does it require a server?

```
$.get("http://xxxxx.com", function (data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

That's all I got but it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: @Tushar - are you sure it should work, cross origin for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript way to do file\_get\_contents()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693518/is-there-a-javascript-way-to-do-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but You can not retrieve data from a different domain using jquery Due to browser security restrictions.

Yes you can use other scripts like perl to scrap html data from third party url.

by using jquery and ajax you do retrieve data from your own web-site.