# Can I use something like file_get_content in js?

Tags: javascript, file-get-contents

I was making a website and I need to store output of a URL in a js variable..can I do that?

I know I can use PHP for that purpose but I want to know is there any technique to store the output of a URL in a js varible??

Comment: Related: _[What is AJAX and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work)_

Comment: You'll need `AJAX` for that task, that's the best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript way to do file\_get\_contents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693518/is-there-a-javascript-way-to-do-file-get-contents)